# c++ curl undefined reference to _imp__curl_easy_init Codeblocks

Tags: c++, curl, codeblocks, libcurl

downloaded precompiled libcurl from github, linked library to project and included header file and i'm trying to run simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>


static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  std::string readBuffer;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but i'm receiving errors

undefined reference to _imp__curl_easy_init
undefined reference to _imp__curl_easy_setopt
undefined reference to _imp__curl_easy_perform
undefined reference to _imp__curl_easy_cleanup

can anyone help me? i'm on windows 10 and using codeblocks 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this define before including curl:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
```

It seems like you're statically linking to curl, but curl requires to be told about this in order for it to expose the implementation.